# Modify a tabular environment so that it can break over pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I am working with a template which has the following new environment for defining a list:

```
%% List environment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{13cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

The problem is that my list grows a bit too long so it doesn't break over the page limit: [image: screenshot].

I read some articles that point towards the use of longtable package, but if I modify the code to add longtable it gives MANY errors.

```
%% List environment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{longtable}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{longtable}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{13cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Comment: Please, provide a complete, minimal working example (MWE). What happens if you do not put the longtable in an environment (longtable is an environment)?

Comment: `\begin{longtable}{\textwidth}{` longtable does not have a width argument like that, remove `{\textwidth}` but 999 times out of 1000 it is better to use a list environment to set a list not a tablem then page preaking is automatic.

Comment: why do you have an `l` column as the second column and then use `\parbox[t]{13cm}{` it would be simpler just to use a `p{13cm}` column then not need special markup in the entry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as I mentioned in the question body, I took a template and modified it to fit my needs. That particular section I did not write/design/think of myself. I can certainly change things to a simler way if there is a way to generate the same output (see the screenshot, hopefully the grayboxes I masked with isn't too distracting)

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any usable example so this is untested but it looks like you do not need a table construct at all:

```
%% List environment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{entrylist}{\par\raggedright}{\par}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
 \makebox[2cm][l]{#1}parbox[t]{13cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4}\par\smallskip}
```

would allow page breaks between each entry and aligns without any table construct as the date is forced into a box of known width (2cm here)